# counting number with 3 csvs python

Tags: python, csv, row

I have 3 csv that i will like to change one column to a running number that depends on the number on rows in the file.
For exmaple, file 1 got 400 rows, file 2 got 240, and file 3 got 100.
so the added column for file 1 will be running number from 1 to 400.
so the added column for file 2 will be running number from 401 to 640.
so the added column for file 3 will be running number from 641 to 741.

what I wrote is this

```
file1 = str(path) + "file1"
file2 = str(path) + "file2"
file3 = str(path) + "file3"
files = [file1, file2, file3]


class File_Editor():
    def line_len(self):
        for k in range(0,2):
            file_name = open(files[k] + ".csv")
            numline = len(file_name.readlines())
            print (numline)
```

I am stuck with making the running number for each file by remembering the number of row that were on the file before.

Thanks Alot!

+++++EDIT+++++

@roganjosh Thanks alot, I used your code with a little fixed for the running_number = 1, I have put it inside the def, that both files will have the same running number.

One last thing, How can I add at the first row Index, for example, "Number" 
and then from the 2nd row, run the running_number_in_csv.

Thanks

Comment: What is `files`? How does `range(0,1)` (which is just '0') open 3 files? Also, your `print` statements are after `return` and so never print anything. Naming the file `file` - the python builtin - is not good practice. There's a number of issues but not enough information to point you in the right direction currently.

Comment: I am in the process of writing a more detailed answer to this as I have gone through your previous questions. Previous questions most likely should have been closed but aren't, meaning that you don't get your answer and your underlying issue (a misunderstanding of functions) keeps cropping up. If you wish to reply to my comments, please do so by "add comment" and reference me with "@roganjosh" and please don't reply to answers with writing a new answer. Nobody will see it and it clutters the format of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your previous questions that are left open, the common theme is fundamental issue with understanding in how to use functions in Python that isn't being addressed. I will try and unpick part of this to prevent similar questions arising. I'm assuming you come from a scientific background like me so I'll stick to that.

You never pass arguments to your functions, only `self`. Instead you try to reference globals from within the function, but there is no need and it is confusing. For example, I might have the equation `y = x^2 + 3x + 5` that is both a mathematical function and can be a python function.

```
def quadratic(value_of_x):
    y = (value_of_x **2) + (3*value_of_x) + 5
    return y

eg_1 = quadratic(5)
print (eg_1)
eg_2 = quadratic(3)
print (eg_2)

# But this will fail
#print (y)
```

`y` exists only within the Python function as a local variable and is destroyed once you leave the `def / return`  block. In this case, `eg_1`, `eg_2` assume the value of `y` at the end of the function and `value_of_x` assumes the value that I put in brackets on the function call (the argument/variable). That's the point of functions, they can be used over and over.

I can also pass multiple arguments to the function.

```
def new_quadratic(value_of_x, coefficient):
    y = coefficient*(value_of_x **2) + (3*value_of_x) + 5
    return y

eg_3 = new_quadratic(5, 2)
print (eg_3)
```

Not only can I not get a value for `y` outside of the scope of a function, but a function does nothing unless it's called. This does nothing; it's the equivalent of knowing the formula in your head but never running a number through it - you're just defining it as something that your script *could* use.

```
starting_number = 5

def modify_starting_number(starting_number):
    starting_number = starting_number * 2
    return starting_number

print (starting_number)
```

Whereas this does what you expected it to do. You call the function i.e. pass the number through the formula.

```
starting_number = 5

def modify_starting_num(starting_num):
    starting_num = starting_num * 2
    return starting_num

starting_number = modify_starting_num(starting_number) # Calling the function
print (starting_number)
```

With that out of the way, on to your question.

```
import csv

files = ['file_1', 'file_2']

def running_number_in_csv(filename_list):
    """ running_number resets every time the function is called, but is 
    remembered within the function itself"""
    running_number = 1 

    for individual_file in filename_list:
        new_rows = [] # Make something to hold row + extra column

        # Read contents of each row and append the running number to the list
        with open(individual_file + '.csv', 'r') as infile:
             reader = csv.reader(infile)
             for row in reader:
                 row.append(running_number)
                 new_rows.append(row)
                 running_number += 1 # Increments every row, regardless of file name number

        # Write the list containing the extra column for running number
        with open(individual_file + '.csv', 'w') as outfile: # Might need 'wb' in Windows
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            writer.writerows(new_rows)

get_running_number = running_number_in_csv(files) # CALL THE FUNCTION :)
```

Answer (score 0):

@roganjosh I have fixed my code.
I know what is the lenght on the file, now i need to add a column with running numbers like:

file1
1 to 400

file2
401 to 641

file 3

642 to 742

Thanks alot!

Comment: As I said in my comment, please don't reply to my comments with writing an answer. Also, this will not fix your misunderstanding. I will still write my answer to try stop you having similar problems in the future.